# Increase all elements of a list except the first one in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `T1`. I want to increase all elements of `T1` by `1` except the first element. How do I do so?

```
T1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
T2=[i+1 for i in T1]
```

The current output is

```
T2= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The expected output is

```
T2= [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Slicing! `T1[0:1] + [... in T1[1:]]`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slicing!

```py
T1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
T2 = [T1[0]] + [i+1 for i in T1[1:]]
```

Or, with `enumerate`:

```py
T1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
T2 = [x+(i>0) for i, x in enumerate(T1)]
```

Output:

```py
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Very clever usage of `(i>0)`, love it.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the first element from the rest and increment the rest by 1 -

```py
first, *rest = t1
t2 = [first] + [(i + 1) for i in rest]
```

Or you could `enumerate` your list and use the index -

```py
t2 = [(val + 1) if idx > 0 else val for (idx, val) in enumerate(t1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be to slice the T1 list in two, the part that you don't want to modify and the part that you do. Just combine them afterwards:

```
T1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
T2= T1[0:1] + [i+1 for i in T1[1:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods, 2 of them

```
T2 = [T1[0]] + [ j+1 for j in T1[1:]]
```

a longer but funnier one

```
T2 = [x+y for x,y in zip(T1, [0] + [1]*(len(T1)-1))]
```

or just a for loop with index, so you can decide which index to operate in

```
T2 = list()
for i,el in enumerate(T1):
    if i == 0:
        T2.append(el)
    else:
        T2.append(el+1)
```

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this:

given:

```
t1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

the `t2` list may be calculated as following:

```
t2 = t1[0:1] + [v + 1 for i, v in enumerate(t1) if i != 0]
```

The first part of the list concatenation is a list: in fact if you try `t1[0]` you get a `TypeError` due to the fact that is impossible to concatenate `int` with `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
for i in range(1,len(T1)):   
  T1[i]=T1[i]+1
```

This would not create a new list, but would change the values in the current list

Answer (score 0):

Relatively simple answer where you use if else condition.

```py
T1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
T2 = [x+1 if i>0 else x for i, x in enumerate(T1)]
```

```py
# Output:
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```